# Nielsen--Schreier for fields

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory, fields, transcendence

Is it true that a subextension of a purely transcendental extension is itself purely transcendental?

In symbols, suppose we have field extensions $M/L/K$, with $M/K$ purely transcendental. Must $L/K$ be purely transcendental?

Comment: No, that is not true.  This was a conjecture of Lueroth (I do not know how to make the umlaut in comments).  The first counterexamples were found by Clemens-Griffiths, with further counterexamples discovered shortly thereafter by Iskovskikh-Manin, Artin-Mumford, etc.

Comment: A small history point: this was not conjectured by Lüroth —  Lüroth only proved the case of transcendence degree 1. Actually I do not think it was ever conjectured: the italian geometers  proposed quite early a number of possible counter-examples, unfortunately with unsufficiently rigorous arguments. I do not know (and I'd be interested to know) who first called it the "Lüroth problem".

Comment: @abx.  Thank you for the explanation.  I always thought this was a conjecture.  I am glad to learn the true history.

Comment: Ah, very interesting, thanks! Where can I find the proof of the degree one case?

Comment: You can find it for instance in Bourbaki's *Algebra V*, exercise 11 of §3. I guess many algebra books have a proof; Wikipedia quotes  *A Course in Constructive Algebra* by Mines-Richman, Universitext, Springer  (1988), p. 148.

Comment: Just to note: it is also true if $M/K$ has transcendence degree 2.

Comment: @potentially dense: well, only if $K$ is algebraically closed — otherwise there are easy counter-examples.